# A javafx listview in a modal stage has some scroll problems with a few device models

Tags: android, listview, scroll, javafx-8, gluon-mobile

With some tablets (samsung galaxy tab A – Android 7.1.1) and smartphones  (Honor 6), it is not possible to scroll down/up a list of 7 items, each item including an image and some short text. In this case, this list stays in the same state. But it is possible to select one of the displayed items. This list appears in a modal box.

That works fine with many other devices. Have you an idea about this trouble?

Thanks

```
Stage stagePopUpMenuPrincipal = new Stage();
stagePopUpMenuPrincipal.setTitle("title of the product");
VBox popUpWindow = new VBox();
stagePopUpMenuPrincipal.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        ...

listeDesAvatars = new ListView<String>();
listeDesAvatars.setMinWidth(POPUP_WIDTH_BYDEFAULT / 2.5);
listeDesAvatars.setMinHeight(POPUP_HEIGHT_BYDEFAULT / 2); 
for (String pseudo: User.listeDesPseudos){
             listeDesAvatars.getItems().add(pseudo);
}

listeDesAvatars.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

int iSelect = 0;
for (User user : User.listeDesUsers) {
    if (user.getPseudo().equals(GluonApplication.userCourant.getPseudo())){
            break;
    }
  iSelect++;
}

listeDesAvatars.getSelectionModel().select(iSelect); // it allows to select all the line including the avatar

     // Note that AvatarScoreCell method provides an item of the listview listeDesAvatars. Each item includes an image and some text. 
listeDesAvatars.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                @Override
                    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
                    return new AvatarScoreCell();
                        }
                    });         

                avatarsListener = new ChangeListener(){
                 @Override
                 public void changed(ObservableValue obs, Object ov, Object nv){
                    for (User user : User.listeDesUsers) {
                        if (user.getPseudo().equals(nv)) {
                            GluonApplication.userCourant = user;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }};



 listeDesAvatars.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(avatarsListener);
 listeDesAvatars.setMinSize(POPUP_WIDTH_BYDEFAULT- 3*DELTA_POPUP, POPUP_HEIGHT_BYDEFAULT - 2*DELTA_POPUP);

          ...

HBox zoneChoixPseudo= new HBox();
zoneChoixPseudo.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
HBox.setMargin(zoneChoixPseudo, new Insets(TOP_ZONE, RIGHT_ZONE, BOTTOM_ZONE, LEFT_ZONE));
zoneChoixPseudo.getChildren().addAll(listeDesAvatars,otherData);

        ....

popUpWindow.getChildren().addAll(zoneTitle, zoneChoixPseudo, ...);

Scene sceneMenu = new Scene(popUpWindow, POPUP_WIDTH_BYDEFAULT + DELTA_POPUP, POPUP_HEIGHT_BYDEFAULT);

stagePopUpMenuPrincipal.setScene(sceneMenu);
stagePopUpMenuPrincipal.show();
```

Comment: It is not recommended at all to use new Stage/Scene on mobile to create popups. If you are using Gluon Mobile, you already have Layers (PopupView, SidePopupView,...) that are better suited for that. As for the ListView issue, try to use the `CharmListView` control instead (even if you don't set headers).

Comment: Why it is not recommended? Could you give us the use restrictions? The Stage/Scene library is provided by the development environment for a long time and, in my case, it  works well on several representative kinds of smartphones and tablets (about 10 kinds at this day), excepted for this mentioned point. Commonly, I use the basic methods of Stage/Scene. And the product is ready to be commercialized. So, it is difficult to use another technology, now :)

Comment: Of course, you can use secondary Stage/Scene on mobile. But it is not so performant as if you just keep one primary stage with a single scene, and you only change the content of that scene. With Gluon Mobile Views and Layers you just do that.